# what does tipbot mean in LKML?

Tags: linux-kernel

I often see `tip-bot for XXX` in LKML(Linux Kernel Mail List). Such mails are often composed of a commit .

I've searched around and still not find what 'tip-bot' means.
Could anyone help explain it?

Comment: http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/What-is-tip-bot-td603228.html

Comment: Also: http://lwn.net/Articles/357483/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tip-bot` is an automated script that notifies the `LKML`(linux kernel mailing list) whenever a certain code or patch has made its way into few of the branches maintained by Peter Anvin, Thomas Gleixner, and Ingo Molnar. I think the `tip` refers to the `tip trees`.